# Converting given Geometry into a PointCollection in ArcGIS

Tags: javafx, desktop-application, arcgis

I'm working on JavaFX desktop application and using the ArcGIS SDK v100.7.0. There is a scenario in my code, where i need to create a `Polyline` from a `Geometry` object. I'm getting this geometry from the `SketchEditor` using `sketchEditor.getGeometry()`. I actually want to add a `Point` to the sketchEditor geometry when in Polyline creation mode using the point Lat Long inserted by the user and not by mouse click on map. How do i get the sketch geometry into a `PointCollecion`, add my new Point into the collection, create `Polygon` from this collection and then pass this polygon back to the `sketchEditor.start()` method. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem after going through the classes and documentation, i figured out how i can get a `Polyline` from a `Geometry` object. The approach was:

```
PointCollection pc = new PointCollection(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
PolylineBuilder pb = new PolylineBuilder(pc, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
pb.replaceGeometry(sketchEditor.getGeometry());
pb.addPoint(new Point(Double.parseDouble(longField.getText()),Double.parseDouble(latField.getText()), SpatialReferences.getWgs84()));
sketchEditor.start(pb.toGeometry(), SketchCreationMode.POLYLINE);
```

I created a new `PointCollection` object, passed it into a new `PolylineBuilder` object. To pass the given `Geometry` into the `PointBuilder`, i used its `replaceGeometry()` method so that it can have the updated geometry. Now i was able to manipulate it and add `Point` to it, which is what i was trying to do.